# emacs: how to kill a process running in current window?

Tags: emacs

I know we can kill using the following if we know the name of the process.

```
(delete-process (get-process "compilation"))
```

But how to know the process running in current window?

I am using gradle mode for java. And when use "gradle run" to run the command in a windows, sometime I need to kill it without it runs too long. But need a way to know the process name. I will be nice to have some function to get the process name running in current window.

Comment: How about `(delete-process (get-buffer-process (current-buffer)))`?

Comment: Closing as a duplicate, as the accepted answer + comments for the other Q&A cover this exact scenario.

Comment: `C-h f delete-process` also tells you that `(delete-process nil)` deletes the current buffer's process.